# Data science python error- ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science, valueerror

I am working on doing some statistical analysis in python however I am new to the field and have been stuck on an error.

For background, I am computing a set of sample_means for each sample size, 200 times.  I am then calculating the mean and standard deviation for each sample size, which are then stored in arrays. This is my code:

```
in[] = 
sample_sizes = np.arange(1,1001,1)
number_of_samples = 200
mean_of_sample_means = []
std_dev_of_sample_means = []
for x in range (number_of_samples):
    mean_of_sample_means.append(np.mean(sample_sizes))
    std_dev_of_sample_means.append(np.std(sample_sizes))

in[] = # mean and std of 200 means from 200 replications, each of size 10
trials[0], mean_of_sample_means[0], std_dev_of_sample_means[0] 

out[] = (10, 500.5, 288.67499025720952)
```

I am now trying to plot the data with the following input:

```
plt.plot(sample_sizes, mean_of_sample_means);
plt.ylim([0.480,0.520]);
plt.xlabel("sample sizes")
plt.ylabel("mean probability of heads")
plt.title("Mean of sample means over 200 replications");
```

However when I do, I get thrown the following error:

```
242         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
243             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 244                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
245         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
246             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (200,)
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong? I feel like its probably something obvious that im not seeing as I am new to this. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Hi, Could you try editing the code to be the actual code that you used to generate the `ValueError`? Including all module imports, and variable definitions (e.g., `trials` doesn't exist)

Comment: I thought the same but I think the OP copy ans pasted from a notebook

Comment: I think your `mean_of sample_means` will have a constant entries of 500.5 for all 200 of them. Same with `std_dev_of_sample_means`, it will've 288.67499025720952

Comment: Your `sample_sizes` array is a constant array of [1,2,3....1000] over all the 200 iterations. You are calculating mean and std_dev on this constant array 200 times **not** on a random sample(subset) from this set.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
plt.plot(sample_sizes, mean_of_sample_means)
```

need both arguments to have the same shape (because you need x and y for your plot on some cartesian coordinate-system; to be more precise: the same size in regards to the first dimension as seen in the error: `if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]`).

But:

```
sample_sizes = np.arange(1,1001,1)  # 1000 !
```

and:

```
number_of_samples = 200
mean_of_sample_means = []
for x in range (number_of_samples):
    mean_of_sample_means.append(np.mean(sample_sizes))  # mean by default over flattened-structure
                                                        # so i assume: 1 element per iteration
# 200 !
```

And as expected, the error gives exactly this info: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (200,)`

Comment: How to deal with this problem?